# How to link against boost.system with cmake

Tags: c++, macos, boost, linker, cmake

I use a cmake generated makefile to compile a c++ file that depends on the boost filesystem library.

During the linking process I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "boost::system::get_generic_category()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in FaceRecognizer.cpp.o
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in FaceRecognizer.cpp.o
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in FaceRecognizer.cpp.o
  "boost::system::get_system_category()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in FaceRecognizer.cpp.o
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in FaceRecognizer.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/ImageMarker] Error 1
```

The action from the makefile that generates this error is this line:

```
cd /Users/janusz/Documents/workspace/ImageMarker/Debug/src && /opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -g -verbose -Wl,-search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -fPIC CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/ImageMarker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/Image.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/XMLWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/FaceRecognizer.cpp.o  -o ImageMarker  -L/opt/local/lib ../libTinyXml.a /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
```

Some googling showed me that this error seems to be common on macs with the boost file system library because I have to link against a boost.system library or make my project depending on the boost.system library.

How do i force cmake to link against the library without hardcoding the library path?

Here the result from otool:

```
otool -L /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
 /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib:
 /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)  
 /opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)   
 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
 /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.0.0)
```

Comment: Janusz, please do "otool -L /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib" and give us the result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

On linux CMake figures itself that boost_filesystem is linked against boost_system.  Obviously you have to tell it explicitly on Mac:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
#...
target_link_libraries(mytarget 
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
)
```

Comment: This is bizarre. On Linux, boost.filesystem dynamic library refers to boost.system library, so no explicit linking to boost.system is necessary. Any idea why this is not happening here?

Comment: You are rigth, ldd libboost_filesystem.so lists libboost_system.so (0x00007fcd31e67000). AFAIK on Mac "otool -L" is the equivalent to ldd, but I have no Mac around.  Should we bring up this at the boost ML?

Comment: What about using ${Boost_LIBRARIES} instead? Should always include everything specified by COMPONENTS, no?

Comment: Good answer... I personally found this answer more helpful though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake/3917033#3917033

Answer (score 11):

This is not an "answer" to the posted question, but an observation on my Ubuntu box.

To use the Boost libs, you have to explicitly write something like this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex system filesystem REQUIRED)
```

In addition, you need to link it this way:

```
target_link_libraries(binary
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
)
```

Or using component targets since CMake 3.15:

```
target_link_libraries(binary PUBLIC
    Boost::regex
    Boost::system 
    Boost::filesystem
    )
```

This follows what Maik says, but not only on Mac.