# How to include external library (boost) into CLion C++ project with CMake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion

I have the following setup for C++ development:

- `OS X Yosemite`
- `CLion 140.2310.6` (a cross-plattform C/C++-IDE by JetBrains using `CMake` as build system)
- installed `boost` via `brew install boost` into `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/`

Now, my goal is to setup a simple project and include the `boost` library. I defined just one **test.cpp** file that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost>

using namespace std;

int test() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4) 
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") 

include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/include/boost")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ./test.cpp)
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I build the project, I get the following error:

> /Users/nburk/Documents/uni/master/master_thesis/MyProject/test.cpp:2:10:
>   fatal error: 'boost' file not found
>
> make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1 
>   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all] Error 2 
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/rule] Error 2 
>   make: *** [MyProject] Error 2

I played around with adjusting paths here and there and also using `add_library` and `target_link_libraries`, none of which made the project build successfully.

**Can someone point into the right direction how to make sure I can include `boost`s functionality into my CLion C++ project?**

**Update:**
Thanks to @Waxo's answer I used the following code in my **CMakeLists.txt** file which:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I now got past the **file not found**-error, but instead I get the following:

> CMake Error at /Applications/CLion
>   EAP.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:685
>   (file):
>
> file STRINGS file "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/boost/version.hpp" cannot   be read.
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:11
>   (find_package)

Any ideas what I am still missing? The referred line (685) in **FindBoost.cmake** is:
`file(STRINGS "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}/boost/version.hpp" _boost_VERSION_HPP_CONTENTS REGEX "#define BOOST_(LIB_)?VERSION ")`

Comment: Do not set the `Boost` variables manually. `find_package` should work out of the box. If it does not, you should pass `Boost_DIR` to the `cmake`command. Do not write system-specific paths in the CMakeLists.txt. The whole point of cmake is to be cross-platform. Platform specific configuration should be rarely required, and if it is the way to do that is to pass the configuration parameters via command line or via cmake-gui.

Comment: if I don't include it, I get back to the **file not found**-error... however, I am sure that I am missing something else and your advise seems to make sense to me! my main problem is that I fail to understand some of the basics of how how CMake actually works, so I guess I've got to sit down and do my homework since I cant seem to find a trivial solution...

Comment: I noticed now that your boost installation is in a non-standard path (`/usr/local/cellar`). [The proper way](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html) to notify cmake to look for boost in that directory is to invoke cmake with `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0 ... `

Answer (score 70, accepted):

After spending the whole afternoon on the issue, I solved it myself. It was a rather stupid mistake and all the hints in @Waxo's answer were really helpful.

The reason why it wasn't working for me that I wrote `#include <boost>` within my **test.cpp**-file, which apparently is just wrong. Instead, you need to refer directly to the header files that you actually want to include, so you should rather write e.g. `#include <boost/thread.hpp>`.

After all, a short sequence of statements should be enough to successfully (and platform-independently) include `boost` into a `CMake` project:

```
find_package(Boost 1.57.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

These lines are doing the magic here. For reference, here is a complete **CMakeLists.txt** file that I used for debugging in a separate command line project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

project(BoostTest)

message(STATUS "start running cmake...")

find_package(Boost 1.57.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()

add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

endif()
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! For OS X users: this will also work when you've installed Boost using Homebrew.

Comment: I've installed `boost` with MacPorts and it seems that CLion (`version 1.2.4`) managed to find it automatically (without any changes in `CMakeLists.txt`).

Comment: Is it the same in Window??

Answer (score 18):

Try using CMake find_package(Boost)

src : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

It works better and CMake is made for cross compilation and giving an absolute path is not good in a CMake project.

**Edit:**

Look at this one too : [How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake)

Because you don't link actually the boost library to your executable.

CMake with boost usually looks like that :

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) # only find static libs
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.57.0 COMPONENTS date_time filesystem system ...)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_executable(foo foo.cc)
  target_link_libraries(foo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this question too and it actually worked so that I didn't get the **file not found**-error anymore... however, I now get a new error: `file STRINGS file /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/boost/version.hpp" cannot
  be read.`... I updated my question, any ideas?

Comment: Theorically you don't have to set Boost_INCLUDE_DIR and Boost_LIBRARY_DIR, it's the work of the find_package(Boost) line.
And don't forget the linking line. If the error still persists maybe have a look at the rights on the file.

Comment: Thank you. It was a pleasure to help, i have hard times when i started CMake, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find boost library using find_package() of clion. So my solution is download to the latest version boost from the following site:

`https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/`

After that, extract it and navigate to that folder in `CMakeList.txt` to include boost library.

`include_directories("/path_to_external_library")`

In my case, I use linux and so I put it under /usr/share/.

`include_directories("/usr/share/boost_1_66_0")`