# Configuring Boost Library in CLion

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion, lib

It is my First time to use Boost lib, So of course I ran into problem:

First this is the CMAKELISTS.txt for my project:

```
    ===========================================
    src/CMAKELISTS.txt:
    =========================================== 
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
    project(My_String)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    set(SOURCE_FILES MyString.cpp MyString.h main.cpp)

    add_executable(My_String_src ${SOURCE_FILES})
    ===========================================
    test/CMAKELISTS.txt:
    ===========================================
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
    project(My_String)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(SOURCE_FILES MyStringTest.cpp)
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\Boost\\boost_1_71_0")
    set(Boost_LIBRARIES "C:\\Program Files\\Boost\\boost_1_71_0")

    find_package (Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories(../src)

    add_executable (Boost_Tests_run ${SOURCE_FILES})

    target_link_libraries (Boost_Tests_run ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    ==============================================
    top_level CMAKELISTS.txt for the whole project:
    ==============================================
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
    project(My_String)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

    add_subdirectory(src)
    add_subdirectory(test)
```

Note: I have built the BOOST lib!`enter code here`
In MyStringTest.cpp I have:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyString_Test_Suite

#include <iostream>
#include "MyString.h"
#include "MyString.cpp"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

The error that I get when I build the project:

```
    [ 50%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/Boost_Tests_run.dir/MyStringTest.cpp.obj
    [100%] Linking CXX executable Boost_Tests_run.exe
    C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-P\mingw64\bin\ar.exe: unable to rename 'CMakeFiles\Boost_Tests_run.dir/objects.a'; reason: File exists
    mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [test\CMakeFiles\Boost_Tests_run.dir\build.make:86: test/Boost_Tests_run.exe] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:141: test/CMakeFiles/Boost_Tests_run.dir/all] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:148: test/CMakeFiles/Boost_Tests_run.dir/rule] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:130: Boost_Tests_run] Error 2
```

What is wrong with my configurations?
And what do i need to do to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake) See also [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindBoost.html).

Answer (score 0):

The code is telling the linker to link this library `../src` to your executable. This is an invalid operation, so remove this line:

```
target_link_libraries(Boost_Tests_run ../src)
```

The arguments to [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) are reserved for **targets** and **library names** (including full paths to library files). The `../src` argument does not fit either of those criteria, as it is simply a directory.

---

EDIT: Another potential issue is your `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable. Again, this should not be provided to `target_link_libraries()` if it just contains a directory path. It should instead contain the **full path** to the libraries, including the library names.

However, the modern `FindBoost.cmake` module provides a better approach. If you know the Boost components you want to use (e.g. `filesystem`), you should specify those components in your `find_package()` call:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
```

Then, the find module will populate *imported* targets for you, and you can link to them like this instead:

```
target_link_libraries(Boost_Tests_run PUBLIC Boost::filesystem)
```

I suggest taking a look at some of the examples on this [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

Comment: After removing the line that you suggested to remove, I get this error when bulding the project:
[ 60%] Built target My_String_src
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable Boost_Tests_run.exe
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-P\mingw64\bin\ar.exe: unable to rename 'CMakeFiles\Boost_Tests_run.dir/objects.a'; reason: File exists
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [test\CMakeFiles\Boost_Tests_run.dir\build.make:86: test/Boost_Tests_run.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:141: test/CMakeFiles/Boost_Tests_run.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2

Comment: @AmjadAlissa I expanded my answer. Like in the first answer I posted, you **cannot** simply use directories in calls to `target_link_libraries()`, they must be actual libraries. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers! It is the first time i use boost and i really spent alot of time trying to figure out how to make the project work but with no success so far. 
Again I did exactly as you said, I modified the cmakelists.txt to be like:
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
target_link_libraries (Boost_Tests_run Boost::unit_test_framework)
I get this error:  Could NOT find Boost (missing: unit_test_framework) (found version
  "1.71.0")