# Problem with cmake and boost library during compilation

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile the following library https://github.com/jgasthaus/libPLUMP that use cmake in order to generate the makefile.

The library includes also the boost library.
The `cmake` command seems to work well, indeed the linking goes good.

```
MBP-di-Giulio-2:libPLUMP giuliopn$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.72.0", minimum required is "1.72.0") found components: program_options serialization iostreams filesystem system 
-- Found GSL: /usr/local/lib/libgsl.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.dylib  
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "4.0.1") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib (found version "3.5.1") 
CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:566 (message):
  SWIG_ADD_MODULE is deprecated.  Use SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bindings/CMakeLists.txt:15 (SWIG_ADD_MODULE)


CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:607 (message):
  Policy CMP0078 is not set: UseSWIG generates standard target names.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0078" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:567 (swig_add_library)
  bindings/CMakeLists.txt:15 (SWIG_ADD_MODULE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:460 (message):
  Policy CMP0086 is not set: UseSWIG honors SWIG_MODULE_NAME via -module
  flag.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0086" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:702 (SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/share/cmake/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:567 (swig_add_library)
  bindings/CMakeLists.txt:15 (SWIG_ADD_MODULE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   plump

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/giuliopn/Thesis/Internet_Codes/Pitman-Yor/libPLUMP/build
```

But when I compile, it doesn't find the boost file:

```
MBP-di-Giulio-2:build giuliopn$ make
Scanning dependencies of target plump
[  6%] Building CXX object src/libplump/CMakeFiles/plump.dir/context_tree.cc.o
In file included from /Users/giuliopn/Thesis/Internet_Codes/Pitman-Yor/libPLUMP/src/libplump/context_tree.cc:17:
In file included from /Users/giuliopn/Thesis/Internet_Codes/Pitman-Yor/libPLUMP/src/libplump/context_tree.h:24:
In file included from /Users/giuliopn/Thesis/Internet_Codes/Pitman-Yor/libPLUMP/src/libplump/config.h:25:
/Users/giuliopn/Thesis/Internet_Codes/Pitman-Yor/libPLUMP/src/libplump/mini_map.h:26:10: fatal error: 
      'boost/scoped_array.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/libplump/CMakeFiles/plump.dir/context_tree.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/libplump/CMakeFiles/plump.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I only modify the version of the boost library in the file `CMakeLists.txt` ( from `Boost 1.35.0` to `Boost 1.72.0`).

For information I'm currently using macOS Catalina v10.15.3

Do you have any suggestion ?

Sorry if the question is not so intresting, but I haven't so much experience with cmake.

Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: Do not use *images* for logs: instead, add this logs into the question as **text**. See [ask].

Comment: Well, [src/libplump/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jgasthaus/libPLUMP/blob/master/src/libplump/CMakeLists.txt) script doesn't add Boost include directories. While top-level [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jgasthaus/libPLUMP/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) uses `find_package()` for locate Boost, it doesn't add Boost include directories too. You may report the problem to the (only) project's developer.

Comment: Probably, adding `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` into the main `CMakeLists.txt` just after `find_package(Boost)` would help in resolving the issue. For other ways just search for "cmake use boost" or similar phrases. See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I miss that question. Now it works.