# how to add boost via -I flag to meson.build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, build, meson-build

### Introduction:

The main objective is having the ability to debug c++ code with `F5` (`Run->start debugging`) in *vs code* via *meson/ninja* build system.

This can be done by following *stenosis*'s answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4919). Unfortunately, this feature has broken when I added *boost* library to the project. The program won't compile via `F5`, because *vs code* running *meson* as a task can't find the boost library:

```
meson.build:33:0: ERROR: Dependency "boost" not found, tried system
```

(Note that `meson compile` works, because I defined `export BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_78_0/`).

**Question**

I have a feeling that the solution is to add `/usr/local/boost_1_78_0/` to search directory (`-I` flag) in `meson.build` file. **How can one specify this?**

---

### Notes and tried approaches:

1. I added `-I` and `/usr/local/boost_1_78_0/` as arguments to `tasks.json` according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626610/how-to-set-up-boost-for-visual-studio-code) (I include only boost headers in my project), but then I get:

> > Executing task: 'meson build --buildtype=debug && cd builddir && ninja' -I /usr/local/boost_1_78_0/ <
>
> /usr/bin/bash: meson build --buildtype=debug && cd builddir && ninja: command not found

2. I typed `meson configure -Dpkg_config_path=/usr/local/boost_1_78_0/` but this didn't work.
3. Meson [documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#boost) specifies setting the custom path to the library in [native files](https://mesonbuild.com/Machine-files.html), but I didn't work it out thoroughly. At a first glance, it looks like overcomplicated approach to a simple problem.
4. (slightly tangent) Debuging with `F5` in *vs code* can also be triggered by specifying [`backend_startup_project`](https://mesonbuild.com/Build-options.html#startup-project) in Meson `build.file`. This worked for me on former version of Meson (0.58.?), but now (v. 0.60.3) I come across [this bug](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/8174) and I must comment out this fragment or I get `meson.build:4:25: ERROR: Expecting rparen got id`.

**EDIT:**

- I add boost as the dependency in the following way:

```
boost_dep = dependency('boost')

executable('main', 'main.cpp', sources : sourcelist, dependencies : [..., boost_dep])
```

Comment: Ps. I use Ubuntu on WSL2

Comment: How did you add boost to the project? Did you use dependency() as in https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#boost ?

Comment: Correct, I also wrote it explicitly in the question.