# Error "Could not find Boost" (missing: context headers)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've added boost like this: "-DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=/boost_1_71_0"
and this is what I get:

> Could NOT find Boost (missing: context headers) (found suitable
> version   "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.71")

Cmake can determine boost version but cannot find boost at the same time!
Is there a way for me to fix it?

This is how I include boost in my cmake file. Nothing fancy in here.

```
find_package(Boost 1.71 COMPONENTS context headers REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Show us your `CMakeLists.txt` file. In general, use `find_package` along with `FindBoost.cmake` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake ; Also see if you're setting the min required version somewhere in your cmakelists file.

Comment: It could be that your CMake does not understand boost 1.71 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost context and headers are **header only** libraries and therefore do not need to be mentioned in the `find_packages` call. Do a simple `find_package(Boost 1.71 REQUIRED)` and you are done. Later you can reference the Boost header directory either with `Boost::boost` or `Boost::headers` in your `target_link_libraries`command.