# How do I compile C++ code with Boost on Msys2

Tags: c++, boost, msys2

I (think) that I have all the libraries installed that I need, e.g.,

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost
```

Also the common development libraries that the msys2 install documentation recommends. I am testing it out with these includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
```

I've tried various permutations such as below with the same error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lboost_programoptions -I /mingw64/include/boost/ -o main
main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: boost/program_options: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <boost/program_options>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How do I get boost with msys2 working?

---

Update:

Because of the question of @HolyBlackCat I discovered that there are two different versions of gcc installed, gcc 10.2 and mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 10.3 . I'm not sure which one I should get rid of. See below, `pacman -Rcns`  is intended to mean, "remove this package and all of its dependencies" as per [here](https://linuxhint.com/remove_package_dependencies_pacman_arch_linux/).

```
$ pacman -Rcns gcc
checking dependencies...

Packages (6) binutils-2.36.1-4  msys2-runtime-devel-3.2.0-14
             msys2-w32api-headers-9.0.0.6158.1c773877-1
             msys2-w32api-runtime-9.0.0.6158.1c773877-1
             windows-default-manifest-6.4-1  gcc-10.2.0-1

Total Removed Size:  319.23 MiB

:: Do you want to remove these packages? [Y/n] n

$ pacman -Rcns mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
checking dependencies...

Packages (7) mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada-10.3.0-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran-10.3.0-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc-10.3.0-5  mingw-w64-x86_64-isl-0.24-1
             mingw-w64-x86_64-libgccjit-10.3.0-5
             mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest-6.4-3
             mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-10.3.0-5

Total Removed Size:  507.78 MiB

:: Do you want to remove these packages? [Y/n] n

$
```

---

Update #2

I uninstalled gcc 10.2 and started mingw64 vs. msys and now I get this:

```
user@host MINGW64 /c/Users/user/boostexample
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -lboost_program_options
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Update #3

I needed to invoke the compiler with:

`g++ main.cpp -o main -lboost_program_options-mt`

and it compiled fine. I suppose I should find where in the documentation these norms are specified.

Comment: You should compile with corresponding mingw, not with g++.

Comment: mingw provides g++, though? I was leaning toward the idea that the library location was not specified, but I'm not as familiar with boost.

Comment: In your MSYS2 shell prompt, what is written in majenta letters, MINGW64 or MSYS? What compiler do you have installed, `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` or `gcc`?

Comment: Is there a regular file (not a directory) with this exact path `/mingw64/include/boost/boost/program_options` on your system?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it says "MSYS" and I seem to have BOTH gcc and mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc packages installed

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. There is nothing at that location

Comment: Uninstall the plain `gcc`. Restart your shell using `mingw64.exe`. Remove the unnecessary `-I ...` flag.

Comment: Try `-lboost_program_options-mt` perhaps.

Comment: *"should find where in the documentation these norms are specified"* For the last advice (adding `-mt`) I didn't look in any docs. I opened `/mingw64/lib` and found `libboost_program_options-mt.a` and `libboost_program_options-mt.dll.a`. Remove the extension and replace `lib` with `-l` and you get your flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curating HolyBlackCat's comments into an answer that worked for me:

1. Use `mingw64` shell, not `msys*`. (Not sure what purpose the division into multiple binaries serves. Perhaps it matters for other windows versions.)
2. Search for the archive file under `/mingw64/lib` that matches what you wanted to compile against. So if `foobar` is name of the functionality you wanted look for `libfoobar.a` there.
3. compile with `g++ main.cpp -o main -lfoobar`

Comment: Although it is irrelevant to the subject, I recommend you to use a builder such as Meson and CMake for your projects instead of compiling your codes manually. Meson is the easiest and most meaningful build tool for C++ by the way. Since Meson uses Ninja build tool to build your projects, it also decreases compile time so much.

Comment: Struggling with this one too right now but I managed to compile the program because of this. One question though, Did you run with any errors while executing the `main.exe`? In my case, it compiles fine but the resulting program is not launching properly.

Comment: @Eliazar as I recall, it worked fine. I would create a separate post and reference this one if needed there.

Answer (score -1):

Install them using `pacman`.

```
 $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

Create a [CMakeList.txt with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake), using OLen's answer.

See also: https://www.msys2.org/docs/cmake/

```
$ cmake ..
-- Building for: Ninja
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: C:/msys64/mingw64/include (found suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.40") found components: program_options
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: build
```

In the above, I have used only 'mingw-64', this will allow the binary to run on regular windows if you have DLLs in '/mingw64/bin' on your path.

The other toolchain (un-prefixed g++) requires an msys2 shell to run the program from (at least that is the easiest way).