# How can I add Boost.Python to CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Given that I could not resolve my problem using conan in my previous question, I have instead resorted to packaging it myself. However, while other questions of similar nature exist and do have answers, in particular I have been looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake/43885372#43885372). I believe this answers are insufficient.

I have setup my `CMakelists.txt` as the following,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(BoostExample)

find_package(Boost 1.83 COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

add_executable(boost_example src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(boost_example Boost::python)
```

I have downloaded the Boost library and placed it into my folder structure, but I do not understand how this links together. The CMake command `find_package` will find a file ending in `<PackageName>ConfigVersion.cmake` or  `<lowercasePackageName>-config-version.cmake`. This is not inside the Boost library what I have downloaded from [their official site](https://www.boost.org/users/download/).

Which steps are missing in order to link Boost.Python to a CMake project after download, given that the Boost library should not contain CMake specific files inside of it.

As a resort I cannot run CMake and receive the following error,

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR python) (Required is at
  least version "1.83")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2378 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

Comment: see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#hints for where cmake looks for boost. e.g. add `-DBOOST_ROOT="directory you installed boost to"` to your cmake command (or just go back to using conan)