# PCL build with issue with boost::throw_exception

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library, msvc12

How can I get around missing `boost::throw_exception` while building PCL?

I've built PCL on Windows (MSVC 2013) a few times in the past, but I've never see this error.  It's been blocking me all today and yesterday:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const &)" (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXAEBVexception@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<struct pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::list_property<unsigned char,signed char> >(struct pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::list_property<unsigned char,signed char> *)" (??$?0U?$list_property@EC@ply_parser@ply@io@pcl@@@shared_count@detail@boost@@QEAA@PEAU?$list_property@EC@ply_parser@ply@io@pcl@@@Z) [C:\Users\mrussell\.conan\data\pcl\1.7.2\ntc\stable\build\d63ff451cbfa147e3b952f2f3790530e1116d93c\io\pcl_io_ply.vcxproj]
```

It appears that `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is set in `boost\config\compiler\visualc.hpp`, which prevents `boost/throw_exception.hpp` from defining it.

I've tried to set `TPN_WIN32` to `/EHsc` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847817/1861346)) both through CMake and via the project properties in Visual Studio to no avail, and even tried sneaking a definition into a high level PCL include (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691561/1861346)), nothing worked.

My CMake generator is `Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64` and my definitions are:

```
-DBOOST_ROOT:PATH=%CONAN_BOOST%
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%CONAN_PCL%
-DEIGEN3_DIR:PATH=%CONAN_EIGEN%\share\eigen3\cmake
-DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=%CONAN_EIGEN%\include\eigen3
-DFLANN_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=%CONAN_FLANN%\include
-DFLANN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=%CONAN_FLANN%\lib\libflann_cpp.so
-DQHULL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=%CONAN_QHULL%\include
-DQHULL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=%CONAN_QHULL%\lib\libqhull.so
-DGTEST_ROOT:PATH=%CONAN_GTEST%
-DBUILD_surface_on_nurbs:BOOL=ON
```

I've tried:

- Removing Qt & VTK
- With Boost 1.60, 1.66, and 1.59
- Linking against a shared and static versions of boost. (PCL does not seem to like shared boost on Windows...)
- Attempting to build shared and static versions of PCL

I feel like I'm chasing the wrong thing, or am missing something.  Maybe I'm missing a `_CPPUNWIND` [define for exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.120).aspx)?  I'm really just stuck.

Comment: I ran into this just now, but I wasn't working with PCL, just boost. The problem was that I just installed vs2017, but went back to vs2015. Apparently the vs2017 installer messes with the vs2015 installation, so I had to uninstall vs2017 and repair vs2015. After that the error went away. I hope this helps.

Comment: hmm, that does probably help actually.  I've taken a break from that build this week, but next week when I have to go back to it, I'm going to try on another (fresh) Windows computer with msvc.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think anything really changed.. But after taking a break on this for a week, this bug seemed to have disappeared.  The only thing I might have changed (so much back and forth that it was hard to keep track) was being more explicit with the C++11 flag.  But I really have no useful comments for anyone else fighting this issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

`TPN_WIN32` is a user defined variable on that post you reference. You need to append `/EHsc` to your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to pass it to the compiler.

Unrelated but really suspicious `-DFLANN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=%CONAN_FLANN%\lib\libflann_cpp.so` is a unix dynamic library. You can't link it on windows with MSVC.

Comment: About the `.so`, you're totally right.  I did *edit* the command (to make it more readable) before posting, but it was copied.. I completely missed that, is definitely should be the `.lib`s that exist there.  I'll try make that fix asap.  Thanks.