# std::filesystem / boost::filesystem for mac os

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use std::filesystem(but now at least boost::filesystem), however I've been trying this for a long time, but nothing worked. I use:

1. Mac os Mojave
2. Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
3. VSCode In my cmake file:

`find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)`

And when I call current_path()

```
std::cout << boost::filesystem::current_path();
```

---

Error occured:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::current_path() in libConfigs.a(server_info.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

About std::filesystem I no longer dream, since there is not even a header file `< filesystem >`)

Comment: These are two different things. Please pick one. If you want to make the Boost build work then remove the references to `std::filesystem`

Comment: Okay so you did `find_package`. Did you actually link the libraries too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065729/560648 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285571/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thank you)I didn't link Boost_filesystem... I would be immensely grateful if you would give similar working advice for std::filesystem)

Comment: See the duplicate I added